# Why does Kernel#p print to standard out?

Tags: ruby

Why does Kernel#p print to standard out? Isn't [printf debugging](http://everything2.com/title/printf%2528%2529+debugging) supposed to output to standard error?

Comment: It wouldn't be called "printf debugging", then, would it?  printf() prints to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a global function "q", which works just like "p" except it prints to $stderr.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

module Kernel

  def q(*stuff)
    stuff.each { |thing| $stderr.print(thing.inspect + "\n")}
  end

end

q 'foo'    # => "foo"
```

You may be tempted to use `puts` instead of `print ... + "\n"`.  This code uses `print` to make it thread-safe: `puts` can be interrupted between the time it prints its arguments and the time it prints the new-line, causing output from two threads to appear on one line.  It's seldom that you have code from multiple threads writing to $stdout/$stderr at the same time, so it's not usually an issue.  But this being a debugging tool, you will certainly end up using it to find out what is going on in threads.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assuming Kernel#p is intended for debugging? It writes to stdout just like Kernel#print or printf in C.

If you want to write to standard error you could do:

```
$stderr.puts(x.inspect)
```

By the way, if you really want to use printf debugging I suggest you read this [article about debugging techniques](http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/DebugCPP/Volume/techniques.html)

Comment: Don't you mean `$stderr.puts(x.inspect)`?

Comment: If you want the behavior of Kernel#p, yes.